# How to compare nextLine() to a String

Tags: java

I have an assignment in my APCS class that asks us to make a combination lock and I think I have the basic structure down. However, I keep running into a problem that won't let me compare a raw `nextLine()` to a `String`.

I was wondering if `nextLine()`s are by default `int`s? Or could anyone just tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
    if((in.nextLine()).compareTo(combo))
    {
        System.out.println("The lock is now unlocked.");
        System.out.println("Please enter the combo to unlock: ");
        if((in.nextLine()).compareTo(combo))
        {
            System.out.println("The lock is now locked.");

        }
        else
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

P.s. the ide returns the error: "error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean" and is referring to the if qualifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nextLine()` will always return a String, so that isn't your problem.

`compareTo(str)` returns an negative number if `str` is lexicographically less than the value being compared to, 0 if the Strings are lexicographically equal, or a positive number if the `str` is lexicographically more than the value being compared to.

You want to use `equals(str)`, which returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that compareTo() returns an integer value, not a Boolean.

See the Java API docs for compareTo (in interface Comparable, at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> Method Detail
>
> compareTo
>
> Returns: a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer
>   as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified
>   object.

The simplest way to compare two Strings is to use

```
if (in.nextLine().equals(combo)) { /* code here */ }
```

Watch out for another pitfall in this program, too.  Your first nextLine() and your second nextLine() are actually two separate input lines.  nextLine() returns the next line of input from the reader, so it will return a different line of input each time you call it.  A solution is to save the results of nextLine() as a variable:

```
String enteredCombo = in.nextLine();
if (enteredCombo.equals(combo))
{
    System.out.println("The lock is now unlocked.");
    System.out.println("Please enter the combo to lock: ");
    enteredCombo = in.nextLine();
    if(enteredCombo.equals(combo))
    {
        System.out.println("The lock is now locked.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```